# binding the property of a data object to DOM element's attribute

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm a newbie in Vue.js. I have the following lines of code in my HTML and JS file:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:class="{{item.className}}">{{item.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        className: 'item-1',
        text: 'Item 1'
      },
      {
        className: 'item-2',
        text: 'Item 2'
      },
      {
        className: 'item-3',
        text: 'Item 3'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

What I want to happen is bind the value of each `className` to the class attribute of each DOM element. I hope someone could correct me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `v-bind` you don't need to use the `{{...}}` syntax, because [Vue already assumes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) you will want to use some kind of a property or object.

So you can for example output the value of each `className` simply like this:

```
<li v-for="item in items" v-bind:class="item.className">{{item.text}}</li>
```

Or shorthand version:

```
<li v-for="item in items" :class="item.className">{{item.text}}</li>
```

Or if the classes are always going to follow the pattern of `item-i`:

```
<li v-for="item, i in items" :class="`item-` + i">{{item.text}}</li>
```